# splitting lines of dates and presenting in desired format

Tags: php, date

I am trying to read a file with 1000 lines containing date like: 2017-09-04 yyyy-mm-dd mm*yyyy*dd . first comes the date then current format and then the desired format to convert date into. I am trying to read all data from file into array and explode it on the basis of space. Then first three array position i am taking to convert date in desired format. But it gives error by saying unexpected exception.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents("file.txt");

$keywords = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $homepage);

print_r($keywords);
$len = count($keywords);
for ($i = 0; $i <= $len; $i = $i + 2) {

  $a = $keywords[$i];
  $b = $keywords[$i + 1];
  $c = $keywords[$i + 2];

  $date = new DateTime($a);
  echo $date - > format($c);
}
?>
```

Comment: Why don't you use a [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)-loop for the `$keywords` array? And where is the excpetion thrown?

Comment: For one, those format strings are invalid, (see: [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-parameters)) for accepted format strings] and for two you're going to need to use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to create a datetime from a given string and format.

Comment: Could you post the part of the actual file here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this. The problem is PHP doesn't look at formats like `yyyy-mm-dd`, but rather like `Y-m-d'. Which is what the`preg_replace` functions are for.

```
<?php
$homepage = "2017-09-04, yyyy-mm-dd, mmyyyydd";

$homepage = preg_replace('/yyyy/', 'Y', $homepage, -1);
$homepage = preg_replace('/mm/', 'm', $homepage, -1);
$homepage = preg_replace('/dd/', 'd', $homepage, -1);

$keywords = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $homepage);

print_r($keywords);
$len = count($keywords);
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i += 3) {

  $a = $keywords[$i];
  $b = $keywords[$i + 1];
  $c = $keywords[$i + 2];

  $date = date_create_from_format($b, $a);
  echo $date->format($c);
}
?>
```

[Works here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/eadf7a04672013a7e78b5acef8dfbb1e56ec739c)

Comment: What if i am trying to read data from file which has several dates with their current format and desired formats. so in that case how to take the for loop to 4th array position.

Comment: Sorry? Could you post an example of your data?

Comment: Input definition
An input file for this problem will contain less than 1000 lines of space separated triples. Each line will contain a date, its current format, and the desired output format.
Output definition
Your output should contain the same number of lines as the given input file. Each line should contain the given input date in the desired output format.
Example input
2017-09-04 yyyy-mm-dd mm*yyyy*dd
Example output
09*2017*04

Comment: Is this your school project? ;) In this case, you probably need another question.